# Production Deployment of MVC Application Using EF with multiple instance with same DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, deployment

I am working an application with MVC and EF, the solution structure as follows

1. App1 -- is MVC application
2. App2 -- is WebApi
3. App3 --- is MVC Application
4. Persistence - class library project -with only one dbcontext and logic stuff
5. Domain --class library project - with  all models

   Now App3 is a main application, which is hosted on the root of domain say www.xyz.com 
   and app1 - is hosted in www.xyz.com/Camp which is converted to application in IIS, 
   and App2 is hosted to www.xyz.com/api, which is also converted to application.

for all application connection string is only one means same database (same dbcontext),

Problem :

suppose I change some domain classes properties, in Domain project and migrate to production while deployment using main App that is App3, the DLLs with main application gets updated, but if I don't republish other projects, they all stop working i.e App1 and App2

I know the reason for this, all other applications DLLs not updated with a new one and EF throws error data context has been changed.

I have to republish all projects to the respective folder to get all working, this is getting hectic, so is there any nonhectic process to this.

Comment: Two initial thoughts, can these be moved to the same project or solution? The VS build process is pretty good at updating things and should keep the downtime to a minimum. VS also handles multiple projects within a solution pretty well.

Comment: @joshua  All projects are in same solution, deploy folders are different

Comment: You can manually create an app offline file to disable sites during the deployment. It sounds a little like you may want to reevaluate the structure of the project based on the uptime/support needs of the application. For instance, An API can easily be added to an MVC project and it is almost trivial to update routing to give a /camp folder (areas are really good for this). This is especially true if there is a single database. You can always use a load balancer for multiple instances of the site if you are close to the performance limit of each server.

Comment: @JoshuaMorgan yeah, need to reevalluate the structure, for mvc project and api, but now the camp folder is published on different domain with same database and dbcontext